# What is the difference between Strict 2Phase Locking and 2Phase Locking?

Tags: database-theory

I have read some notes about the two but yet still confused about why there is a need for the strict 2phase locking. Based on some slides,

[Two Phase Locking](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep544/99au/lectures/class13/sld014.htm)  and  [Strict Two Phase Locking](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep544/99au/lectures/class13/sld015.htm)

They have a single difference which is :

1. If transaction T releases any lock, it can acquire no new locks. <-
   2PL
2. Hold all locks until end of transaction. <- S2PL

I will like a practical example of a Transaction in both strict and normal.Highlighting the differences.

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly two reasons for adopting Strict 2PL rather than Basic 2PL, explained in [1].

- The first reason is about the time when a 2PL scheduler can release some (read/write) lock owned by some transaction on some data item.
- A second reason for the scheduler to keep a transaction’s locks until it
  ends, and specifically until *after* the DM processes the transaction’s Commit or
  Abort, is to guarantee a *strict* execution. Strict executions are recoverable and avoid cascading aborts (ACA).

---

[1] [Chapter 3 "Two Phase Locking" in the Book "Concurrency Control and Recovery in Database Systems"; Page 59](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/philbe/chapter3.pdf). By Bernstein et al., 1987.